# how to return boolean using mysql EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get a boolean output to a mysql query.

i issue a query like the following

```
EXISTS (
    select 1 
    from someothertable 
    where someaccid = (
       select someid 
       from smtable 
       where username = 'someuser' 
       and password = 'somepassword')
)
```

This returns an error `1064` in the `mysql` shell and returns a bool false in `php mysqli` .

How can i get an output as bool using `EXISTS` command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `SELECT`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (select 1 
               from someothertable 
               where someaccid = (select someid 
                                  from smtable 
                                  where username = 'someuser' and 
                                        password = 'somepassword'))
```

This will return `1` if `EXISTS` is successful, `0` otherwise.